# Salesforce Rest API OAuth - Bad Response Error

Tags: c#, rest, oauth, salesforce

Any help here is appreciated. Im simply trying to do the basic call to the Oauth Username-Password Flow. Its giving me a Bad Request (400) Error right when I try to call GetResponse().

```
        string sessionId = String.Empty;

        string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SfdcLoginUrl"].ToString();

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("grant_type=password&");
        sb.Append("client_id=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"].ToString() + "&");
        sb.Append("client_secret=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"].ToString() + "&");
        sb.Append("username=" + HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(username) + "&");
        sb.Append("password=" + HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(password));

        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
        }

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        sessionId = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: you sent the contenttype to be json, but you're not sending json.

Comment: Appologies, I should have specified. Changing the content type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" also yields the same error. This was just the settling left in my (somewhat blind, at this point) fiddling

Comment: you aren;t encoding the clientId or secret. also when you get a 400 look at the response body, that'll have more info

Comment: Just cleaning this post up. Of all things, it turned out that this type of request needs to either be on a domain/box that whitelists the SalesForce domain, OR include a user security token on the end of the password. Thanks, superfell, for your insight here - much appreciated!

Comment: If you were able to answer your own question, please post the solution as an answer.

Comment: Also check if it is the TLS version. [VB.NET - Salesforce POST Request returns 400 Bad Request Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482611/vb-net-salesforce-post-request-returns-400-bad-request-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

password should be **password+security token** if not your ip address white listed in salesforce remote access area

Comment: 'm also facing same issue, may i know how do you resolved it?

I tried the same request through postman and able to received successful response. but in C# i'm seeing 400 error message

URL: https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=3MxxxxxxrwD.gRq7ynM6WhDqfhH1mNjkTaOdPG9qasd60vfridBSbCFcYpb3Jx11ek3hC8&client_secret=5554461903&username=test_integrat@gmail.com&password=TEST!Y94FSFU0uBasdasdadsa23i

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a link back to offical doc, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm

> "You must append the user’s security token to their password A security token is an automatically-generated key from Salesforce. For example, if a user's password is mypassword, and their security token is XXXXXXXXXX, then the value provided for this parmeter must be mypasswordXXXXXXXXXX."