# VB.NET - Salesforce POST Request returns 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: vb.net, oauth, visual-studio-2015, http-post, salesforce

**NOTE**: I've never written vb.net code before this. I've googled for a solution but did not find anything that worked.

I'm trying to get access token from Salesforce. **Below code worked just yesterday**. And I have no idea why it is not working today. I've tried adding content-type as **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** but it did not work either. When I use curl I'm able to get access token. Also I'm able to get access token using advanced rest client in google chrome. Any ideas why it is returning *400 Bad Request* **unknown error retry your request**?

```
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim clientId As String = "clientId"
    Dim clientSecret As String = "clientSecret"
    Dim redirectUri As String = "https://test.salesforce.com"
    Dim environment As String = "https://test.salesforce.com"
    Dim tokenUrl As String = ""
    Dim username As String = "username@salesforce.com"
    Dim password As String = "passwordtoken"
    Dim accessToken As String = ""
    Dim instanceUrl As String = ""

    Console.WriteLine("Getting a token")

    tokenUrl = environment + "/services/oauth2/token"
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(tokenUrl)

    Dim values As NameValueCollection = New NameValueCollection()
    values.Add("grant_type", "password")
    values.Add("client_id", clientId)
    values.Add("client_secret", clientSecret)
    values.Add("redirect_uri", redirectUri)
    values.Add("username", username)
    values.Add("password", password)

    request.Method = "POST"

    Try
        Dim client = New WebClient()
        Dim responseBytes As Byte() = client.UploadValues(tokenUrl, "POST", values)
        Dim response As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes)
        Console.WriteLine(response)
        Console.ReadKey()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Try

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: What's in the response body when you get the 400 response?

Comment: I've tried output responseBytes but it shows null. Also debugging mode shows it as null.

Comment: I haven't used this in years, but from what i remember, there's a specific exception you catch, and it gives you access to the response body for that error condition.

Comment: @superfell well I got response using WebException. It says unknown error, retry your request. This code works on login.salesforce.com with respected credentials but does not work on test.salesforce.com. Weird thing is I'm able to get access token with Java code from test.salesforce.com.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, appearently problem was about TLS version mismatch. All Salesforce sandboxes refuse TLS 1.0 connections. Our vb.net test code was using TLS 1.0 thus returning an error. It would be great if Salesforce would return better error code.

All I needed to do was add a line of code on top of the code block:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
```